# Have any maintained VisualBasic code in GIT Repo? If yes, How do you manage build and Test?

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, continuous-integration

My code base consists of majority of VB6 Code , I am trying to host it on TFS-GIT Repo but just checking if I can automate the build of such application

Answer (score 0):

> but just checking if I can automate the build of such application

The short answer is yes.

Since VB6 is not installed on the hosted agent, to build the Visual Basic code, we need to create a machine that has `VB6` and the Visual Studio Team Services build agent on it.

You can check the following document for some more details:

[How to use TFS 2012 Team Build for Visual Basic 6](https://www.ecanarys.com/Blogs/ArticleID/68/How-to-use-TFS-2012-Team-Build-for-Visual-Basic-6)

[Build Visual Basic 6.0 Applications with Visual Studio Team Services](http://donovanbrown.com/post/Build-Visual-Basic-60-applications-with-Visual-Studio-Team-Services)

Hope this helps.